# Filtering date in kendo grid with inherited model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kendo-grid, filtering

I want to filter bithdate in a kendo grid with asp.net core MVC.
I have two model inherited, for example:

```
public class ParentModel
{
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
}

public class ChildModel : ParentModel
{
    public string BirthDateAmerican => BirthDate.ConvertEnglishToAmerican();
}
```

I want to filter date in a kendo grid with a date input that writen in american format, but date stored in database is in English format, Then i need to convert it for filtering in model, for this purpose i use linq queryable to get all data and filter it with request received from grid by ToDataSourceResultAsync(request) extension method.

for ex:

```
public Task<DataSourceResult> GetListByKendoFilter(DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            return Queryable
                .Select(x => new ChildModel
                {
                    Id = x.Id,
                    ParentModel.BirthDate = x.BirthDate
                }).OrderByDescending(o => o.BirthDate).ToDataSourceResultAsync(request);
        }
```

the filter input in request is in American format that should be compared with english format date field that stored in database.and i get this error.

The LINQ expression {expression...} could not be translated.
Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated,
or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either
AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().
See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information."}
System.Exception {System.InvalidOperationException}.

It seems that date change method in childmodel doesnt executed and the format is not comparable with database.

Pls do not change the senario and give your solutions for this senario.
Excuse me for bad english :)

Comment: `but date stored in database is in English format,` No it isn't. Dates are stored as numbers. Same with `DateTime`.

Comment: Does the query execute if you use `ToList` rather than `ToDataSourceResultAsync`? _This is not a long term solution - just narrowing down where the issue is._

Comment: is the date stored as a date in the database, or as a varchar?

Comment: Yes date is stored in database as datetime. but the typing style is english format. And date in filtering query is string